# Cannot find Python.frameworks in OS Sierra

Tags: macos, python

I am trying to find Python.framework under ~/Library/Frameworks but it's not there.  I need it to create a path from a software leading to my mac's Python including its bin and lib folders.  I only see Samsung Kies in my Frameworks folder.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal.app.

Start the python interpreter by typing:

```
python
```

type the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

to quit the interpreter type:

```
quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Having similar problem with you. After some headache, I found that in macOS Sierra, the Python frameworks is located in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The Python framework lives in the main System Library directory, not your home directory's Library. So, you'll find it here:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```